# Java Play 2.5 with WebSockets and Actors

Tags: java, playframework, websocket, akka, actor

After reading this one
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWebSockets
I have noticed that `LegacyWebSocket` is deprecated now.

This example shows how to communicate without deprecated method and with `Actors`.
https://github.com/playframework/play-java-websocket-example.
But there is no communication between actors and In.

Does anyone able to implement communication from Input to Actors and back without deprecatedcode in Java? Or maybe subscribe actors for every input information?
Thank you.

Comment: I wonder about this too. Since Play moved to Akka Streams for the WebSockets it is difficult to understand. I wonder why they still use the LegacyWebSocket in their Java documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWebSockets.